# Namespace - logically grouping classes

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns, namespaces

I understand how to physically group classes i.e. inheritance, composition etc.  However, I have never truly understood the benefit of namespaces (logical grouping of classes).  I usually have a namespace for the presentation layer, a namespace for the business logic layer and a namespace for the data access layer ie.:

```
com.Application.BusinessLogicLayer  
com.Application.PresentationLayer
com.Application.DataAccessLayer
```

Sometimes the presentation layer will have more than one app e.g. VB.NET app and ASP.NET app.  Sometimes the business logic layer will be split into multiple DLLs.

I could answer an exam question on what namespaces are but I have difficulty applying the knowledge to a problem domain.  For example, have a look at the code below:

```
Namespace com.application.businesslogiclayer
    Public Class ClassA
        Private CB As ClassB
    End Class
End Namespace
Namespace com.application.businesslogiclayer
    Public Class ClassB
        Private CC As ClassC
    End Class
End Namespace

Namespace com.application.businesslogiclayer
    Public Class ClassC

    End Class
End Namespace
```

As ClassA has a composition relationship with ClassB and ClassB has a composition relationship with ClassC, then I believe they should all belong in the same namespace e.g.

> com.application.businesslogiclayer.classABC

.  However, you can bring in other classes using the 'Import' statement, so perhaps this is not correct.

What criteria do developers use when designing namespaces?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Namespaces are useful for not only logically grouping types but also for avoiding naming collisions among types as the namespace is also part of the full type name. For example, you may have a class named Log in your application but you also reference another assembly written by someone else that also has a class named Log. There may be a practical reason to use both Log classes in some implementation (i.e. because they do different types of logging or one is for logging info and the other represents a piece of a tree) and namespaces allow the compiler to differentiate between the two Log classes. Don;t discount the usefulness of using namespaces for grouping as this becomes more important on large projects.

As far as criteria, start with a single namespace. As your application evolves you may want to unclutter your single namespace with two or more nested namespaces to better organize your code, maybe to collapse some code you're not currently working on in the IDE to get it out of your way but the groupings should be logical and meaningful. In .NET, follow the desgin guidelines and examples of the namespaces in the base class library.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the reference to avoiding conflicts between types.  I have asked a similar question about DLLs here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901617/multiple-dlls-for-one-layer, in case you have time to answer.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend reading the [Types and Namespaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229050%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) page of the [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229042%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This details when you should use namespaces, and provides general guidance.

In general, organizing your types into separate namespaces where related features are grouped into a namespace helps keep your projects organized.

In your case, you might want to put all of your main business logic into one namespace, but separate out your presentation logic into its own namespace.  This helps in many ways, including allowing the compiler to help prevent you from mixing concerns (you can't use the wrong classes without explicitly adding an Import statement).

This also helps avoid type name collisions, so you can have simple, clean, understandable names within each problem area.

Comment: Thanks, +1 for the second link.  I have asked a similar question about DLLs here: stackoverflow.com/questions/14901617/…, in case you have time to answer.