# Multiple DLLs for one layer

Tags: vb.net

I usually split projects into layers i.e. presentation layer, business logic layer and data logic layer.  Sometimes I will separate the layers using namespaces and sometimes I will have three separate DLL's (using tiers).

I see developers splitting tiers into multiple DLL's.  For example, I once saw a business logic layer with over one hundred different project files and hence over one hundred different DLLs.  Also the MSDN documentation shows that the .NET framework contains multiple DLL's e.g. mscorlib etc.

I believe that the reasoning behind having separate DLLs is that it minimizes the memory footprint and also it allows multiple developers to work on different projects e.g. one team could work on one project and another team on another project etc.

I work in a two developer team.  What criteria do developers use deciding to split into separate DLLs?

Comment: Separate dlls does not aid memory footprint unless some projects can elect not to use a dll at all.  If the whole set is always used together then there is no memory benefit.

Comment: @tcarvin, could you post an answer so that I can give credit?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c#: why use DLLs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793599/c-why-use-dlls)

Comment: @Hnas Passant, thanks.  To be honest I did not see this question before posting.  However, I am asking about the criteria that developers use, but then I suppose reusability etc are criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separating code into more than one assembly is done for many reasons, some more technical than others. Assemblies can be used for logical grouping of code much like namespaces and, in fact, one common pattern is to separate large namespaces (concerns) into separate assemblies for that namespace. But that reason is most definitely not the best reason to use more than one assembly.

Code reuse is like the number one factor for placing code into different assemblies. For example, you may have a console application and all of the code in is the one execute file that is compiled. Later on, you decide to create a web app front-nd for the same application. Instead of copying the core code from your console app to your web app, you would likely refactor the solution into three projects: a class library for the code code (the main implementation), a console app (which already exists) and a web app. The console app and web app projects/assemblies will reference the class library project/assembly and the main code is reused across both implementations. This is an oversimplification, mind you.

Another reason to separate code into multiple assemblies to separate concerns while managing dependencies. In this case, you may have code that requires references to web-oriented dependencies (other assemblies) that you may not want to reference in your core application assemblies. You would do that so that you may reuse your core assemblies without taking unnecesary dependencies  when they are not needed by breaking up the app into additional assemblies/projects.

Another reason is to facilitate concurrent development of a large team where sub-teams may each work on a different assembly, helping to reduce the number of "collissions" between developers working on different concerns of the application.

Answer (score 1):

> What is the reasoning for separating layers into multiple DLLs?

There are various reasons to do this.

1. It adds isolation, which can help the compiler prevent you from mixing concerns.  Without adding a reference explicitly, you can't use internal types in the other DLLs "by accident", which allows the compiler to help you keep your code cleaner.
2. If you don't use an assembly at runtime, it won't be loaded.  This can keep the memory footprint smaller.  (If all assemblies are used, however, it won't help).
3. It provides a logical separation within your APIs and projects, which can help with organization and maintainability of your code.  Note that too many projects is just as bad (or sometimes worse) than too few, however, as many projects adds complexity that may not be beneficial.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for point 1.  I had already thought of points 2 and 3, but thanks for confirming these points anyway.  Is there criteria that developers use to decide how to split into DLLs?